# Use existing window in another tab

Tags: javascript, window

I have the main page (called 'main.html'), with a link on it, with which I can open a popup or focus the popup if already existing: `var test; if (test == null || test.closed) test = window.open('test.html','test','width=800,height=600,location=0'); else test.focus();`

Works fine, but here comes the problem: If the user opens the main page more than one time in his browser, clicks the link in main #1 and then clicks the link in main #2, it uses the existing popup, but reloads the site, because he doesn't know, that the popup is already opened.

Is there a way, that I can tell the other main windows the handle of the popup, so they can use it?

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Yes. There are some functionality blocked by browsers for security and this is a rare condition and the user have to deal this for his weird act... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two "main windows" are opened independently from each other, there is no way for them to access the variables of each other.

You can however get a reference to the window "test" with `window.open`, and then check if a variable you set in "test.html" is defined, to find out if it it's loaded:

```
var test; 
if (!test || test.closed) {
  test = window.open('','test','width=800,height=600,location=0');
  if (test && !test.someVariable) {
    test.location.href = "test.html";
  }
} else 
  test.focus();
```

<s>BTW, notice I changed the check in the first if from `test == null` to `!test`, because the variable will be originally `undefined` and not `null`, so that `test == null` will result in `false`.</s>

Comment: Thank you, opening the window without an url and only setting the url when the page isn't loaded worked.

Comment: Everything fine, but `test == null` would be `true` :)

Comment: @Emmerman: True. I forgot the automatic conversion wenn using `==`. I usually use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

This would need you to being able to access the main window in all the other tabs to check whether any of them have opened a popup. As far I know the only way to get a reference to a window is from the reference returned by the function window.open.

Not allowing javascript to accessing other windows and tabs except inside the window which opened the windows/tabs is due to security. Imagine if javascript could go through all your tabs and run functionality. That would be quite a big security risk.